# radix select using cuda

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I have been working to develop a radix select using CUDA which utilizes k smallest element to sort given number of elements. The main idea behind this radix select is that is scans through 32 bit integer starting from its MSB to LSB. It partitions all 0 bit on left side and all 1 bit on the right side. The side with contains k smallest elements is solved recursively. My partition process works just fine but I am having problem dealing with recursive function calls. I am unable to stop the recursion. Please help me on that!
My kernel function looks like this: This is kernel.h

```
  #include "header.h"
  #define WARP_SIZE 32
  #define BLOCK_SIZE 32

__device__ int Partition(int *d_DataIn, int firstidx, int lastidx, int k, int N, int bit)
{
int threadID = threadIdx.x + BLOCK_SIZE * blockIdx.x;
int WarpID = threadID >> 5;
int LocWarpID = threadID - 32 * WarpID;
int NumWarps = N / WARP_SIZE;
int pivot;

__shared__ int DataPartition[BLOCK_SIZE];
__shared__ int DataBinary[WARP_SIZE];

for(int i = 0; i < NumWarps; i++)
{
    if(LocWarpID >= firstidx && LocWarpID <=lastidx)
    {
        int r = d_DataIn[i * WARP_SIZE + LocWarpID];
        int p = (r>>(31-bit))&1;
        unsigned int B = __ballot(p);
        unsigned int B_flip = ~B;
        if(p==1)
        {
            int b = B << (32-LocWarpID);
            int RightLoc = __popc(b);
            DataPartition[lastidx - RightLoc] = r;
        }
        else
        {
            int b_flip = B_flip << (32 - LocWarpID);
            int LeftLoc = __popc(b_flip);
            DataPartition[LeftLoc] = r;
        }

    if(LocWarpID <= lastidx - __popc(B))
        {

            d_DataIn[LocWarpID] = DataPartition[LocWarpID];
        }
    else
        {

            d_DataIn[LocWarpID] = DataPartition[LocWarpID];
        }
        pivot = lastidx - __popc(B); 
        return pivot+1;
    }

}   
}


__device__ int RadixSelect(int *d_DataIn, int firstidx, int lastidx, int k, int N, int bit)
{

if(firstidx == lastidx)
    return *d_DataIn;
int q = Partition(d_DataIn, firstidx, lastidx, k, N, bit);
int length = q - firstidx;
if(k == length)
    return *d_DataIn; 
else if(k < length)
    return RadixSelect(d_DataIn, firstidx, q-1, k, N, bit+1);
else
    return RadixSelect(d_DataIn, q, lastidx, k-length, N, bit+1);
}

 __global__ void radix(int *d_DataIn, int firstidx, int lastidx, int k, int N, int bit)
{
RadixSelect(d_DataIn, firstidx, lastidx, k, N, bit);
}
```

Host code is main.cu and it looks like:

```
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "kernel.h"

#define BLOCK_SIZE 32
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int N = 32;
thrust::host_vector<float>h_HostFloat(N);
thrust::counting_iterator <unsigned int> Numbers(0);
thrust::transform(Numbers, Numbers + N, h_HostFloat.begin(),         RandomFloatNumbers(1.f, 100.f));
thrust::host_vector<int>h_HostInt(N);
thrust::transform(h_HostFloat.begin(), h_HostFloat.end(), h_HostInt.begin(), FloatToInt());
thrust::device_vector<float>d_DeviceFloat = h_HostFloat;
thrust::device_vector<int>d_DeviceInt(N);   
thrust::transform(d_DeviceFloat.begin(), d_DeviceFloat.end(), d_DeviceInt.begin(), FloatToInt());
int *d_DataIn = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_DeviceInt.data());
int *h_DataOut;
float *h_DataOut1;
int fsize = N * sizeof(float);
int size = N * sizeof(int);
h_DataOut = new int[size];
h_DataOut1 = new float[fsize];

int firstidx = 0;
int lastidx = BLOCK_SIZE-1;
int k = 20;
int bit = 1;
int NUM_BLOCKS = N / BLOCK_SIZE;
radix <<< NUM_BLOCKS, BLOCK_SIZE >>> (d_DataIn, firstidx, lastidx, k, N, bit);
cudaMemcpy(h_DataOut, d_DataIn, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);  
WriteData(h_DataOut1, h_DataOut, 10, N);


return 0;
   }
```

List of headers that I used:

```
   #include "cuda.h"
   #include "cuda_runtime_api.h"
   #include "device_launch_parameters.h"
   #include <thrust/host_vector.h>
   #include <thrust/device_vector.h>
   #include <thrust/transform.h>
   #include <thrust/generate.h>
   #include "functor.h"
   #include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
   #include <thrust/copy.h>
   #include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
```

Another header file "functor.h" to convert floating point numbers to int type and to generate random floating numbers.

```
  #include <thrust/random.h>
  #include <sstream>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <iomanip>
  struct RandomFloatNumbers
   {
float a, b;
__host__ __device__
    RandomFloatNumbers(float _a, float _b) : a(_a), b(_b) {};  
__host__ __device__
    float operator() (const unsigned int n) const{
        thrust::default_random_engine rng;
        thrust::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(a,b);
        rng.discard(n);
        return dist(rng);
}

    };

   struct FloatToInt
    {
__host__ __device__
    int operator() (const float &x)
const {
    union {
        float f_value;
        int i_value;
    } value;

    value.f_value = x;
    return value.i_value;
}
    };

   float IntToFloat(int &x)
     {
    union{
          float f_value;
          int i_value;
        }value;

        value.i_value = x;
        return value.f_value;
     }

   bool WriteData(float *h_DataOut1, int *h_DataOut, int bit, int N)
    {
std::ofstream data;
std::stringstream file;
file << "out\\Partition_";
file << std::setfill('0') <<std::setw(2) << bit;
file << ".txt";
data.open((file.str()).c_str());
if(data.is_open() ==  false)
{
    std::cout << "File is not open" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {

        h_DataOut1[i] = IntToFloat(h_DataOut[i]);
        //cout << h_HostFloat[i] << " \t" <<  h_DataOut1[i] << endl;
        //std::bitset<32>bitshift(h_DataOut[i]&1<<31-bit);
        //data << bitshift[31-bit] << "\t" <<h_DataOut1[i] <<std::endl;
        data << h_DataOut1[i] << std::endl;
    }
    data << std::endl;
data.close();
std::cout << "Partition=" <<bit <<"\n"; 
return true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for a complete application please?  Include the host code, `main`, etc. so that I can copy, paste, and compile and run your code without adding anything or changing anything.

Comment: Hi!I have included my entire code above.Please help me figure out where did I go wrong.

Comment: Your `functor.h` does not compile correctly.  It is missing a return statement and the closing curly brace.  I'm not sure what else is missing.

Comment: I guess it should compile now.

Comment: In order to improve readability on SO, you should consider indenting the code you post here.

Comment: There seems (to me) to be many problems with this code.  To pick just one, as constructed, I don't see how it can work for more than a single warp (i.e. radix select among no more than 32 elements).  I can attempt to get it working, but I cannot fix that limitation without a substantial re-write.  And in general, radix select using anything like your approach (which is crafted after the sequential algorithm of recursive partitioning) will not be easily extensible beyond a single threadblock (i.e. 1024 elements).  Are you interested in that?

Comment: It's just a test code to see if radix select works for single warp.As I soon as I get rid of this recursive issue, I was planning to get it working for multiple warps. I am focused on working with 1024 elements at this time. So, that would be fine, I guess.

Comment: Your code is broken in a lot of ways.  Although you've stated that your partition function is working correctly, it is not.  To get started with debugging, add a statement in your `RadixSelect` function that checks to see if `(bit > 31)` and then just return a safe value to end the recursion.  Then run the code with `cuda-memcheck`.  You'll find that your `Partition` function is generating many out-of-bounds accesses.  You can then vary the bit to return on below 31 and you can eventually find the first call to `Partition` that is failing.

Comment: Could you please post your code here so that I can get a better understanding of it.

Answer (score 1):

Per your request, I'm posting the code I used to investigate this and help me in studying your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

__device__ int gpu_partition(unsigned int *data, unsigned int *partition, unsigned int *ones, unsigned int* zeroes, int bit, int idx, unsigned int* warp_ones){
  int one = 0;
  int valid = 0;
  int my_one, my_zero;
  if (partition[idx]){
    valid = 1;
    if(data[idx] & (1ULL<<(31-bit))) one=1;}
  __syncthreads();
  if (valid){
    if (one){
      my_one=1;
      my_zero=0;}
    else{
      my_one=0;
      my_zero=1;}
    }
  else{
    my_one=0;
    my_zero=0;}
  ones[idx]=my_one;
  zeroes[idx]=my_zero;
  unsigned int warp_one = __popc(__ballot(my_one));
  if (!(threadIdx.x & 31))
    warp_ones[threadIdx.x>>5] = warp_one;
  __syncthreads();
  // reduce
  for (int i = 16; i > 0; i>>=1){
    if (threadIdx.x < i)
      warp_ones[threadIdx.x] += warp_ones[threadIdx.x + i];
    __syncthreads();}
  return warp_ones[0];
}

__global__ void gpu_radixkernel(unsigned int *data, unsigned int m, unsigned int n, unsigned int *result){
  __shared__ unsigned int loc_data[1024];
  __shared__ unsigned int loc_ones[1024];
  __shared__ unsigned int loc_zeroes[1024];
  __shared__ unsigned int loc_warp_ones[32];
  int l=0;
  int bit = 0;
  unsigned int u = n;
  if (n<2){
    if ((n == 1) && !(threadIdx.x)) *result = data[0];
    return;}
  loc_data[threadIdx.x] = data[threadIdx.x];
  loc_ones[threadIdx.x] = (threadIdx.x<n)?1:0;
  __syncthreads();
  unsigned int *next = loc_ones;
  do {
    int s = gpu_partition(loc_data, next, loc_ones, loc_zeroes, bit++, threadIdx.x, loc_warp_ones);
    if ((u-s) > m){
      u = (u-s);
      next = loc_zeroes;}
    else{
      l = (u-s);
      next = loc_ones;}}
    while ((u != l) && (bit<32));
  if (next[threadIdx.x]) *result = loc_data[threadIdx.x];
}
int partition(unsigned int *data, int l, int u, int bit){
  unsigned int *temp = (unsigned int *)malloc(((u-l)+1)*sizeof(unsigned int));
  int pos = 0;
  for (int i = l; i<=u; i++)
    if(data[i] & (1ULL<<(31-bit))) temp[pos++] = data[i];
  int result = u-pos;
  for (int i = l; i<=u; i++)
    if(!(data[i] & (1ULL<<(31-bit)))) temp[pos++] = data[i];
  pos = 0;
  for (int i = u; i>=l; i--)
    data[i] = temp[pos++];
  free(temp);
  return result;
}

unsigned int radixselect(unsigned int *data, int l, int u, int m, int bit){

  if (l == u) return(data[l]);
  if (bit > 32) {printf("radixselect fail!\n"); return 0;}
  int s = partition(data, l, u, bit);
  if (s>=m) return radixselect(data, l, s, m, bit+1);
  return radixselect(data, s+1, u, m, bit+1);
}

int main(){

  unsigned int data[8] = {32767, 22, 88, 44, 99, 101, 0, 7};
  unsigned int data1[8];

  for (int i = 0; i<8; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<8; j++) data1[j] = data[j];
    printf("value[%d] = %d\n", i, radixselect(data1, 0, 7, i, 0));}

  unsigned int *d_data;
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_data, 1024*sizeof(unsigned int));
  unsigned int h_result, *d_result;
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_result, sizeof(unsigned int));
  cudaMemcpy(d_data, data, 8*sizeof(unsigned int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    gpu_radixkernel<<<1,1024>>>(d_data, i, 8, d_result);
    cudaMemcpy(&h_result, d_result, sizeof(unsigned int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("gpu result index %d = %d\n", i, h_result);
    }

  unsigned int data2[1024];
  unsigned int data3[1024];

  for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) data2[i] = rand();
  cudaMemcpy(d_data, data2, 1024*sizeof(unsigned int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<1024; j++) data3[j] = data2[j];
    unsigned int cpuresult = radixselect(data3, 0, 1023, i, 0);
    gpu_radixkernel<<<1,1024>>>(d_data, i, 1024, d_result);
    cudaMemcpy(&h_result, d_result, sizeof(unsigned int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (h_result != cpuresult) {printf("mismatch at index %d, cpu: %d, gpu: %d\n", i, cpuresult, h_result); return 1;}
    }
  printf("Finished\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Here are some notes, in no particular order:

- I got rid of all your thrust code, it's not doing anything useful as far as the radix select algorithm is concerned.  I also find your casting of `float` to `int` curious.  I haven't thought through the ramifications of trying to do a bitwise radix select in order on a sequence of exponent bits followed by a sequence of mantissa bits.  It might work, (although I think if you include the sign bit, it definitely won't work) but again I don't think it's central to understanding the algorithm.
- I included a host version that I wrote just to check my device results.
- I'm pretty sure this algorithm will fail in some cases where there are duplicated elements.  For example, if you hand it a vector of all zeroes, I think it will fail.  I don't think it would be difficult to handle that case however.
- my host version is recursive, but my device version is not.  I don't see that recursion is that useful here, since the non-recursive form of the algorithm is easy to write as well, especially since there are at most 32 bits to travel through.  Still, if you wanted to create a recursive device version, it should not be difficult, by incorporating the u,s, and l manipulation code inside the partition function.
- I have dispensed with [typical cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).  However I recommend it.
- I don't consider this to be a paragon of cuda programming.  If you delve into for example a radix sort algorithm (such as [here](https://code.google.com/p/back40computing/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2FFastSortSm20%2Fb40c%2Fradix_sort)), you will see that it is pretty complex.  A fast GPU radix select would look nothing like my code.  I wrote my code to be analogous to the serial recursive partitioned radix sort, which is not the best way to do it on a massively parallel architecture.
- Since radix select is not a sort, I attempted to write a device code that would do no data movement of the input data, since I considered this to be expensive and unnecessary.  I do a single read from global memory for the data at the beginning of the kernel, and thereafter I do all work out of shared memory, and even in shared memory I am not re-arranging the data (as I do in my host version) so as to avoid the cost of data movement.  Instead I keep flag arrays of ones and zeroes partitions, to feed to the next partitioning step.  The data movement would involve a fair amount of uncoalesced and/or bank-conflicted traffic, whereas the flag arrays allow all accesses to be non-bank-conflicted.